# Dating slang question based on a Murakami story

Tags: slang

In the New Yorker there is an English translation of a story by Haruki Murakami, called Yesterday. I was reading the first part of it to my wife, and the young man speaking asked, "Did she let you go all the way?" referring to the extent of the other young man's sexual experience.

My wife immediately asked whether the common English expression "to go all the way," referring to sexual intercourse, would be that similar in Japanese. I answered that I didn't know, but that it might be a fairly universal concept. I assured her that more detailed American English slang on that topic would not be mirrored word for word.

Well, of course the next sentence mentioned "third base" in the same context. Now I didn't know what to tell her! So I am asking here:

In the US, young people say, using baseball terminology, "first base," meaning  kissing, or "second base," touching the girl's breasts, or "third base," "home plate," or "all the way", meaning the same as home plate or sexual intercourse.

Is there some sort of analogous slang used by young people in Japanese?

Thank you very much, especially for not making fun of my silly question!

Answer (score 5):

Although there's no such baseball metaphor in Japanese, closest Japanese words that came up to my mind are `[A]{エー}`, `[B]{ビー}`, `[C]{シー}`; A for kissing, B for touching, and C for intercourse. (Some sources say `D` means "pregnancy", but I don't think this was used in real life)

> 「どこまで行ったの？」
>   「彼とはまだAまで。」

(*"How far have you reached?"* and *"I've only reached the first-base with him"* may be the translation, but I'm not sure. Edits are welcome.)

However these were frequently used maybe 20 years ago or so, and they are being obsolete. Younger people simply put just `キスまで`, I think.

キスとかの段階を示すABCってあるじゃないですか？ あれって何が何なんですか？
http://detail.chiebukuro.yahoo.co.jp/qa/question_detail/q1246485907

A similar expression of "all the way" is `最後まで(行く or やる)`, which I think is still common. (Did she let you go all the way? = 最後までやらせてくれた?/最後までいかせてくれた?）

Comment: ところでABCの由来って誰かご存知ですか？　実は日本以外でも使われてたりして…