# "B" meaning "hot and heavy"?

Tags: words, slang, loanwords, anime

In Maison Ikkoku, the title of episode 60 is "見ちゃった！響子{きょうこ}と三鷹{みたか}がいきなりB？！", which is translated to "Caught in the Act! Kyoko and Mitaka-Hot and Heavy!"

My question is, what is "B"? I've literally never heard it before @.@. I know "H" and "BL", but I've never heard just "B" to have any meaning in that way.

For context, this is an 80's/90's anime, and Kyouko and Mitaka are a potential couple that are caught embracing (in a misunderstanding where Mitaka fell on top of Kyouko) by Godai, who's also after Kyouko in a love triangle.

[image: title screen]

Comment: Related: [Dating slang question based on a Murakami story](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/17337/5010) Note that this is fairly old slang of the Showa era. I don't think young people use A, B and C this way anymore.

Answer (score 8):

I assume this is [sense 12 in this dictionary](https://www.weblio.jp/content/B), although I haven't heard the term myself as a learner.

> 俗にペッティングのこと。Aをキス、Cをセックスとして、その間の段階ということから。 
> Colloquially, (sexual) petting. From the fact that if A is kissing, C is sex, then B is the stage in between.

If this definition is correct, an equivalently colloquial English translation with a pretty much identical meaning would be ["second base"](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/second_base).

Comment: It also appears in ["Zakennayo!: The Real Japanese You Were Never Taught in School"](https://www.goodreads.com/en/book/show/1258984), where the comparison to first base etc. does appear. So you could also translate it as "heavy petting", potentially.

Comment: As a quick follow-up question: is this slang at all commonly-known nowadays? Or is it much more of an 80s/90s thing? Because "getting to second base" is a commonly known expression even nowadays, but I've basically never heard A/B/C used like this