# What does "B.D." mean here? (Birdie Wing)

Tags: words, slang, loanwords, anime, listening

In Birdie Wing, Eve is being led blindfolded to a golf match that she has to do to settle a mafia dispute. While being explained this absurd premise, she says something in Japanese which is translated as "Sounds like something out of a B.D.".
[image: screenshot of the line being said]
Here's a video version of the line being said: https://files.catbox.moe/obd7gc.mp4

To me, it sounds like she's saying "だからゴルフで決着？まるでベデね。"

Anyways, can anyone translate what "B.D." (or whatever is being said here) means? The only explanation I can think of is "Bluray DVD" (e.g. a movie), but that sounds like a stretch >.<.

Comment: Can't imagine why the downvotes, when I asked a very similar question here ( https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/99783/35659 ) and got lots of upvotes @.@.

Comment: Did you search for what you thought you heard?

Comment: @aguijonazo yes, and all I got was "Blu-ray Disc", which seems like a stretch, as I've never heard it used in such a manner. Am I missing something here? I literally can't understand what I'm doing wrong @.@. I don't just ask questions like an idiot out of hand without trying quite a bit myself.

Comment: Really? https://www.google.com/search?rls=en&q=%E3%83%99%E3%83%87&ie=UTF-8

Comment: @aguijonazo I searched on jisho.org and found nothing, and didn't expect something as weird as "ベデ" to yield any decent results on google. But even so, the best answer that yields is "フランス語圏で広く読まれる、芸術性の高いストーリー漫画。略称のBDから、ベデまたはベーデーともいう", which no japanese neophyte would ever understand. The downvotes are absolutely unwarranted, and an actual decent answer from the community would is what's actually warranted. I'm holding back in describing the kinds of people who would downvote over an honest question like this.

Comment: I didn’t know the word, did search for it, and found what appeared answer your doubt in an instant. At least two other people seem to agree that should have been included in your “quite a bit” of effort.

Comment: @aguijonazo when I mishear something, I look up a bunch of variations of it in an actual dictionary, not google. And if I was a beginner in Japanese and looked it up on google, I would literally not understand any of the articles describing its meaning. I think what the proper thing to do is, instead of downvoting, is to give an actual answer like the one I just added to this question. Good day, and thanks for the help.

Comment: Google translate does an adequate job translating the sentence you mentioned (making it accessible to a Japanese neophyte). I suppose the lesson is that this is one more thing to consider trying.

Comment: @Leebo absolutely, the moral of the story is to ask Google Translate and get answers like this ( https://i.imgur.com/usPykx5.png ), instead of daring to ask a question of Japanese Stackexchange about something that literally no dictionary has a translation of. Thank you! Please downvote me more for my horrible sin, instead of even attempting to give an answer or any context about the word and how it's used in Japan! ^_^

Comment: I didn't downvote you... and the sentence I was talking about was フランス語圏で広く読まれる、芸術性の高いストーリー漫画。略称のBDから、ベデまたはベーデーともいう. (I thought the mention of "Japanese neophyte" would make that clear). As an aside, weblio's デジタル大辞泉 does include an entry for ベデ, so it's not "literally no dictionary." https://www.weblio.jp/content/%E3%81%B9%E3%81%A7

Comment: @Leebo sorry for lashing out at you ;-;. I'm just extremely disappointed by this community and how hateful and elitist they're acting. Instead of providing an answer and decent context in a few seconds, they'd rather say "scour Japanese-only websites using google translate and try to figure it out". That...sounds like the antithesis of what this stackexchange should be for, and I haven't had such an experience here before. Seems like the thing we should fight against.

Comment: @Leebo also, by "no dictionary", I meant "no Japanese-to-English dictionary", which is the kind of dictionary most anyone would use when trying to find the meaning of Japanese words in English.

Comment: I didn't downvote you, and I agree that this question is probably on the "ambiguous enough that it's a decent question" side that warrants being on the site. However, no need to lash out at the whole community! _"I'm just extremely disappointed by this community and how hateful and elitist they're acting."_ — a community necessarily has many voices, and they don't all disagree or agree with you.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to aguijonazo for helping me find the answer.

ベデ / ベーデー is short for the french expression [Bande dessinée](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bande_dessin%C3%A9e), which basically means comic. According to [https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/バンドデシネ/](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/%E3%83%90%E3%83%B3%E3%83%89%E3%83%87%E3%82%B7%E3%83%8D/): it's essentially used to in the same way 漫画っぽい (like a manga) might be used, to poke at how "story-like" something might be.

As for whether this expression is at all common, I don't know, and hopefully someone else can clarify that point.